# Disable SNMPv1 & Activate v2c on Windows Server R12&+

Tags: windows, snmp

We are looking to disable SNMPv1 but keep SNMPv2 on our Windows Server but without installing a 3rd client.

Is there a way nativaly on Windows To keep only the SNMPv2 version ?

Thank you four help, Official documentation didn't really help.

Comment: There is no such setting. Also v1 and v2c are almost the same if you talk about security. If your goal is to remedy security risks, a 3rd party agent with v3 support is unavoidable.

Comment: Great Thank you. It seems logic but we wanted to know if it was possible.